# “There’s a horse running a pal of mine owns a leg of”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ellipses

What does the sentence in bold mean? It from the movie 'Poirot':

> **Poirot**: And you, Hastings, do not you run away with such celerity. I have work for you too.
>
> **Hastings**: Oh! Er... As a matter of fact, I was thinking of popping down to Sandown this afternoon ... ***There's a horse running a pal of mine owns a leg of.***
>
> **Poirot**: When he owns four legs, I pop with you. But now it's time for work, yes?

[Source](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Agatha_Christie%27s_Poirot#The_Adventure_Of_The_Clapham_Cook_.5B1.1.5D)

I am confused. What does Hastings mean? How can a horse run a person (*a pal of mine*)?

Comment: Could it be "has a leg _of_" rather than "has a leg _off_"? If so, then it could mean that the pal has a share in ownership of the horse. That is, he owns one of the horse's legs, not the entire horse. This is outright speculation on my part, I've never heard of such a usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original, << Poirot "And you, Hastings, do not you run away with such celerity. I have work for you too." // Hastings: "Oh! Er... As a matter of fact, I was thinking of popping down to Sandown this afternoon ... There's a horse running a pal of mine owns a leg of." //  Poirot: "When he owns four legs, I pop with you. But now it's time for work, yes?" >> is reasonably transparent. 'Is a joint owner of (perhaps has a quarter share in)'.

Comment: "There's a horse running a pal of mine owns a leg of." could be rephrased of "There's a horse running, which a pal of mine part-owns"

Comment: I took the liberty of parsing the sentence (incorrectly) so that the question stands a better chance of staying open. The sentence itself is quite unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's a horse running a pal of mine owns a leg of

A more verbose example to explain the meaning:

> There's a horse running (in the race). A pal of mine owns a leg of that horse.

If you're asking what "owning a leg of a horse" means; in this case it's means that Hastings' friend **partially owns** that horse.

I'm a bit conflicted about the exact meaning of "owning a leg of a horse". [According to this link](http://www.dnaindia.com/bangalore/report-the-thrill-of-owning-a-leg-of-a-horse-1750087), it directly refers to owning a **quarter** of the horse (since a horse has 4 legs).

But it's also possible that "to own a leg of a horse" is used more broadly, without actually stating that you own exactly 25% of the horse. I can't find confirmation online either way (other than the one site I linked, which is hardly an authoritative source).

---

As I understand it, the construction is grammatically invalidated by interjecting "running" between "a horse" and "a pal of mine owns a leg of".

However, let me slightly tweak the example to make it clear why this is (mostly) correct. Suppose Poirot did "pop" with Hastings. At Sandown, Hastings points at the horse and says:

> There's the horse [a pal of mine owns a leg of].

Notice the similar construction with e.g.

> There's the man [Robert spoke of].

However, I can't think of a single way to correctly place another word between "the man" and "Robert". For example:

> **Wrong**: I gave [the man] a dollar [Robert spoke of].
>   **Correct**: I gave [the man Robert spoke of] a dollar.

[the man Robert spoke of] is one chunk that cannot be split (in its current form).

Applying this to Hastings' statement, it would be more correct to say:

> There's [a horse a pal of mine owns a leg of] running (in the race).

"in the race" is optional, but I think it helps with the readability here, making the meaning of "running" more easily parsable.

Comment: Implied, not inferred. They're making the implication; it's up to you to draw any inference from that.

Comment: @tchrist: I actually meant it as "it's commonly inferred" (not implied by the speaker, but inferred by the listener). I'm somewhat of an imply/infer nazi myself, so I'm aware of the difference between them :) (I owe [Lisa Simpson](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Mommie_Beerest/Quotes) for that). But I do see how my phrasing left it a bit too ambiguous. I removed the infer/imply reference because it's not really an implication to begin with, I'm fairly sure Hastings was stating it directly.

Comment: I disagree about your last part about the "more correct" way to phrase it. Consider the sentence "There's a man who looks like Beethoven playing the piano." vs. "There's a man playing the piano who looks like Beethoven." The second one is the only unambiguous version that implies that the man is playing the piano and looks like Beethoven, and not that he looks like Beethoven playing the piano (whatever the man himself happens to be doing).

Comment: @NuclearWang: I agree with your example, but that relies on (1) one version being inherently ambiguous and (2) the explicit "who" making the sentence structure more easily parsable. A better example would be e.g. "I saw the man Beethoven killed yesterday". It's ambiguous (did he kill him yesterday, or did I see him yesterday?), but the alternative does not sound correct at all ("I saw the man yesterday Beethoven killed"). Note that there is a third option for my example ("Yesterday, I saw the man Beethoven killed"), but this simply isn't the construction Hastings used.

Comment: @NuclearWang: I do agree that explicitly using "who" is generally easier to parse; but I tried to keep my correction as close to Hastings' original sentence as I could, as opposed to rewriting the whole thing.